# How I get the row number in a iteration using RubyXL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyxl

Using RubyXL I want to know what row number my iteration is.

```
    workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("./file.xlsx")

    worksheet = workbook[0]

    worksheet.each do |row|
    test0 = row[0].value
    line = ????
    puts "Line number #{line} - Value = #{test0}"
    end
```

Comment: Would [`#each_with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) solve your problem ?

Comment: This solved my problem quite elegantly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`#each_with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) and write it like this:

```
workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("./file.xlsx")

workbook.first.each_with_index do |row, index|
  puts "Line number #{index} - Value = #{row[0].value}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each_with_index` method while looping to get the current row number of the iteration

```
worksheet.each_with_index do |row, index|
    test0 = row[0].value
    line = index
    puts "Line number #{line} - Value = #{test0}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Call `row.r` to get the current row number.

Not sure when this was added but you can now do the following:

```rb
worksheet.each do |row|
  puts "Row Number #{ row.r }"
end
```

Just keep in mind that the first row number is 1 and is *usually* the column headers/names.